# Getting Phrases from DB or cache it

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have I multi language script. Each language has it owns phrases. on `global.php` I retrieve the data from DB, and put all phrases in an array.

The main problem, there are many people who don't have `Memcached` on there hosting. What is the best way to keep the **performance** high without using `Memcached`.

I have tried to use `sessions`, but with each visitor the script will create another `session`.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you could compile a PHP file from your DB results, which would contain the definition of your phrases array as well as a timestamp (if you need to invalidate your cache based on time). Then, you could include this file. If it contains your phrases array, you don't need to query the database.

Comment: a single optimized db query isnt much overhead, especially if other queries are being issues anyway, amortizing the cost of the db connection. mysql even has a query cache(memory) all set up and automatically working on most servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any persistence store is the answer to your question. It could be the file-system, it could be memcache (memory), it could be a database, it could be N number of other things. Memory is obviously going to be the most performant.

If you're developing an app which you intend to distribute your caching layer should be built so the backend (persistence store) can be easily swapped out at any time. Then implement best-case caching with fallbacks all the way to file then blackhole. But the implementation of your cache shouldn't concern itself with that.

```
$cache = new Cache; // Automatically selects the best cache-mechanism to use
$cacheId = 'languages';

if (!$languages = $cache->load($cacheId) {

  // ... Do the leg-work to get the languages ...

  $cache->save($cacheId, $languages);
}

return $languages;
```

Comment: What do you mean by new `cache` ? I need a class to store something in the memory or what ?

Comment: Your cache manager. The class that stores and retrieves cached information without exposing the nitty-gritty details like which caching mechanism you're using.

Comment: What mechanisms I can use rather than Memcached  in `PHP`?

Comment: File system and memory are the two most generalized locations. Every persistence store that I can think of will use one or both of those mechanisms. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html has a list of supported backends in Zend Framework for example.